# Removing rows from simple table

Tags: tablesorter

I'm trying to figure out how to remove rows from a table. More specifically, rows that user might have ADDED.

Essentially my table gets data from a DB. I have a link "Add Row" that seems to work okay. It'll add a row, and add along the 'save' and 'delete' button on the row. See:

[image: example output table]

As you can see, the idea is to be able to 'cancel' this newly added row. However, I cannot find simple examples on how to do it, nor can I even seem to trigger the click() of the delete button!

My code:

```js
$(function() {

  /* <table id="tableX"> tag to specify different tables to be threated by the Tablesorter */
  var $table = $('#table1');

  var enabledlbl = localejs.gettext("Enabled");
  var disabledlbl = localejs.gettext("Disabled");
  var fieldRequiredlbl = localejs.gettext("This field is required!");
  var dayslbl = localejs.gettext("days");
  var monthslbl = localejs.gettext("months");
  var savelbl = localejs.gettext("Save");
  var deletelbl = localejs.gettext("Delete");
  var accStatuslbl = localejs.gettext("Account Status");
  
  /***************************
   * main tablesorter config
   ***************************/
  $table.tablesorter( {
  theme : "bootstrap",

  widthFixed: true,

  /* click on column header a 3rd time to disable sorting, else need to ctrl+click */
  sortReset: false,


  // widget code contained in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file
  // use the zebra stripe widget if you plan on hiding any rows (filter widget)
  // the uitheme widget is NOT REQUIRED!
  // PROY: eventually also look at the Output Widget
  widgets : [ "columns", "zebra"],

  widgetOptions : {
    // using the default zebra striping class name, so it actually isn't included in the theme variable above
    // this is ONLY needed for bootstrap theming if you are using the filter widget, because rows are hidden
    zebra : ["even", "odd"],

    // class names added to columns (need 'columns' widget) when sorted
    columns: [ "primary", "secondary", "tertiary" ]

    }
  });

  /***************************
   * Add row function
   ***************************/
  $('.addrow').click(function() {
    var row = '' + 
    '<tr class="newrow">' + 
      '<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="0"></td>' + 
      '<td>'+
        '<select name="isActive" id="isActive" class="form-control pl-2" aria-label="' + accStatuslbl + '" aria-describedby="isActiveReq">' + 
          '  <option value="1" selected>' + enabledlbl + '</option>' + 
          '  <option value="0">' + disabledlbl + '</option>' + 
          '</select>' +
          '<div id="isActiveReq" class="pl-1 invalid-feedback">' + fieldRequiredlbl + '</div>' +
        '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + 
          '<input type="text" name="days" id="days" class="form-control"' + 
          '  placeholder="'+ dayslbl +'"' + 
          '  aria-label="' + dayslbl + '"' + 
          '  aria-describedby="daysReq"' + 
          '  value=""' + 
          '  required/>' +
          '<div id="daysReq" class="pl-1 invalid-feedback">' + fieldRequiredlbl + '</div>' +
        '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + 
          '<input type="text" name="months" id="months" class="form-control"' + 
          '  placeholder="'+ monthslbl +'"' + 
          '  aria-label="' + monthslbl + '"' + 
          '  aria-describedby="monthsReq"' + 
          '  value=""' + 
          '  required/>' +
          '<div id="monthsReq" class="pl-1 invalid-feedback">' + fieldRequiredlbl + '</div>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="text-right text-nowrap">' + 
        '  <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="' + savelbl + '" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 1.1em; color: red;">' + 
        '  <input type="button" name="btnDelete" value="' + deletelbl + '" class="delrow" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 1.1em;">' +
        '</td>' + 
      '</tr>';
    
    $row = $(row),
    // resort table using the current sort; set to false to prevent resort, otherwise
    // any other value in resort will automatically trigger the table resort.
    resort = true;
    
    $table
      .find('tbody').append($row)
      .trigger('addRows', [$row, resort]);
    return false;
  });
  
  /***************************
   * Delete row function
   ***************************/
  $('.delrow').click(function() {
    alert("delete row..");
  });
 
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- jQuery tablesorter related -->
<link href="/css/jquery-tablesorter/theme.bootstrap_4.prestadesk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/js/jquery-tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.combined.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/prestadesk.tablesorter.onem_conditions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table table-striped table-md table-responsive-lg w-auto" id="table1">

    <thead class="pt-2">
      <th scope="col" data-priority="critical" data-label="ID" data-filter="false" class="colID">ID</th>
      <th scope="col" data-priority="critical" data-sorter="false" data-filter="false" class="colStatus" data-label="STATUS" data-placeholder="" class="">STATUS</th>
      <th scope="col" data-priority="critical" data-sorter="false" data-filter="false" data-label="DAYS">DAYS</th>
      <th scope="col" data-priority="critical" data-sorter="false" data-filter="false" data-label="MONTHS">MONTHS</th>
      <th data-priority="critical" data-sorter="false" data-filter="false" data-columnSelector="disable" data-label="SPACER" data-name="SPACER">&nbsp;</th> 
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>                  
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>DAYS</th>
        <th>MONTHS</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="pl-3 pt-2 pb-2" style="border-bottom-style: hidden;">
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-auto pr-2">
            [ <a href="#" class="addrow">Add Row</a> ]
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto pl-0 ml-0">
            * save the added row before inserting new ones!                    
          </div>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!-- ID -->
        <td class="pl-3 data-rowheader">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </td>
        
        <!-- STATUS -->
        <td class="text-nowrap">
          <select name="isActive" id="isActive" class="form-control pl-2">
            <option value="1"  selected>Enabled</option>
            <option value="0" >Disabled</option>
          </select>                         
        </td>
        
        <!-- DAYS -->
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="days" id="days" class="form-control"
            placeholder="days"
            value="156"
            required/>
        </td>
        
        <!-- MONTHS -->
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="months" id="months" class="form-control"
            placeholder="months"
            value="18"
            required/>
        </td>

        <!-- FORM BUTTONS -->
        <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
          <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 1.1em;">
          <input type="button" name="btnDelete" class="delrow" value="Delete" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 1.1em;">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that the `$('.delrow').click(function()...` gets properly called if I add the class="delrow" to the main, existing 'delete' buttons, but upon adding a row, even if the new added row button has the 'delrow' class, it doesn't go through the $('.delrow').click even at all.

That is my first problem. Second, as mentioned initially, I can't seem to find a simple example. I am not using any particular widgets here or anything. It's a simple table... Should I ?

I did came across *Pager plugin - examples of how to add and remove rows.* from https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html, however, frankly, I do now understand it. Why would I need the pager just to remove a row? And frankly it seems way overkill, no ?

If anyone can shed a light on this... Many thanks! pat

Answer (score 0):

Use [delegated binding](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) on the delete button:

```
$table.on('click', '.delrow', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  $table.trigger('update');
});
```

Comment: That was simple enough! Why was this so hard to google ? Seems like a common requirement to me ;)  

Anyhow, thanks for your help! Did the trick :))